# Cannot create bean 'datasource' offline

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm trying to use Mybatis in my spring project.

So, I added the code below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

But the problem is that an error occured.
'Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in file [xml file path]'
and 'nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

So I checked if the class really doesn't exist in java code, but it does.

My computer is not connected to internet because of some security issues. 
So I've been suffering from some constraints.

does this(not connected to internet) have something to do with the error????

Here is my stack trace.. 
if you scroll the message all the way to the right, it says 'NoClassDefFoundError'

[image]

Comment: ClassNotFound suggests that a JAR isn't in the CLASSPATH.  I'm not sure why it isn't available, but that's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: you'd better show the full stack trace

Comment: Because of unavailability of the internet, I added all the external library manually( project -> properties -> add external jars)  So, the added library exists in java code (I checked it with import). However, the bean object inside xml file cannot find the class. That is, I think all my xml files cannot find 'jar'.... Is there any way to make my xml recognize jar files???

Comment: I added the full stack trace...